# Calculate RF shielding property of aluminum sheet

Tags: rf, rfid, shielding

I want to quantify the radio-frequency shielding properties of a sheet of aluminum. I have an RFID antenna shooting at 865 MHz and I want to shield the antenna so that I don't pick up tags behind the shield.

How would I solve this? Can I do it analytically or must simulate in software? Approximating is ok.

Data are:

- Consider infinite sheet for simplicity (no edge leakage).
- Aluminum sheet of thickness = 0.15 mm
- Frequency of 865 MHz
- Distance antenna - sheet = 10 cm
- Power = 10 mW (approximate the antenna as a perfect source, no lobes)

Comment: One problem you're going to have is that unless the aluminum sheet is of infinite extent, there will be leakage around the edges of the sheet.

Comment: Also. need to know the directivity of the antenna - how much energy is emitted from the back side (the backlobe) and edges (sidelobes) vs the front (main beam) of the antenna.

Comment: Thank you! I've added these details.

Comment: well, OK, now I'm a bit conflicted: If you can make an unrealistic assumption such as inifinite aluminium sheets, you can do anything, basically, because you stopped caring about the results representing reality.

Comment: Thank you, Marcus. The thing is that I'm simulating a sheet, when in reality the antenna shoots against walls covered in aluminum tape with the specified thickness. The box is enclosed. Yet, experimentally, the aluminum tape must be applied a couple of times to avoid misreadings.
Therefore, I want to simulate a single sheet to demonstrate shortly that the specific thickness I've found experimentally is enough to shield the RF.

Comment: thanks for that info! Certainly seems like it would make a good addition to your question, so that experts in that field know what you're about!

Comment: You need to induce currents on the surface of the sheet nearest the antenna. That's a boundary condition problem, note that almost all of the incident wave is reflected. Then the wave propagates through the sheet, skin depth calculations will be useful there. Then the remaining current launches a wave out of the other side, which will have the same gain as you calculated for the first surface. That's almost perfect isolation for any practical thickness of material. Basically all propagation to the other side will be through slots, seams, edges, imperfections, the things you're ignoring.

Comment: Aluminum tape? With adhesive backing?  Aluminum also forms a tough oxide coating.  All this sounds like electrical connection would be a concern.

Comment: Thank you all. @Neil_UK if the propagation is due to leakage at those spots, why would doubling the aluminum layer thickness fix the misreading issue?

Comment: @rdtsc what do you mean by that?

Comment: If the adhesive is non-conductive, and two pieces of aluminum tape are overlapped without a robust electrical connection, then the close proximity means significant parasitic capacitance is created between the two pieces.  A better idea may be copper tape, with conductive adhesive, then solder a grounding braid to each strip along an edge.  The wider the braid, the better.  This reduces parasitic L and C components and ensures a robust grounding to a wider range of frequencies.

Comment: @rdtsc Thank you, I agree that non-conductive adhesive may cause parasitic capacitance. What is the main concern behind such effect? Is it a safety issue or is it mostly shielding performance?

Answer (score 2):

To quantify the radio-frequency shielding properties of the aluminum sheet in this scenario, you can use  analytical approximations and simulations. Let's break down the process of the analytical approximations.

First, you can use some analytical approximations to get a rough idea of the shielding effectiveness of the aluminum sheet. The shielding effectiveness \$\text{SE}\$ is usually measured in decibels \$\left[\text{dB}\right]\$ and represents the reduction in electromagnetic field strength when passing through a material. It's given by:

$$\left|\text{SE}\right|=\left|20\log_{10}\left(\frac{\displaystyle\text{E}_\text{i}}{\displaystyle\text{E}_\text{t}}\right)\right|\tag1$$

Where \$\displaystyle\text{E}_\text{i}\$ is the incident field strength (without the shield) and \$\displaystyle\text{E}_\text{t}\$ is the transmitted field strength (with the shield).

For an infinite sheet of metal, the shielding effectiveness can be estimated using the "Skin Depth" \$\delta\$ at the frequency of interest. The skin depth represents how deeply electromagnetic waves can penetrate a conductor and is given by:

$$\delta=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\sqrt{\pi\mu_0}}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\sqrt{\sigma\text{f}}}=\frac{\displaystyle500\sqrt{10}}{\pi}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\sqrt{\sigma\text{f}}}\tag2$$

Where \$\mu_0=4\pi\cdot10^{-7}\space\text{H/m}\$ is the vacuum magnetic permeability, \$\sigma\$ is the conductivity of the material (for aluminum, approximately \$3.5\cdot10^7\space\text{S/m}\$) and \$\text{f}\$  is the frequency in \$\left[\text{Hz}\right]\$.

Once you have the skin depth, you can use it to approximate the fraction of the incident field that gets through the sheet:

$$\frac{\displaystyle\text{E}_\text{i}}{\displaystyle\text{E}_\text{t}}=\exp\left(-\frac{\displaystyle\text{d}}{\displaystyle\delta}\right)\tag3$$

Where \$\text{d}\$ is the thickness of the sheet.

Now you can plug this fraction into the shielding effectiveness formula to get an approximate shielding effectiveness in dB. So, we end up with:

$$\left|\text{SE}\right|=\frac{\displaystyle20}{\displaystyle\ln\left(10\right)}\cdot\frac{\displaystyle\pi\text{d}\sqrt{\sigma\text{f}}}{\displaystyle500\sqrt{10}}\approx0.01725814\text{d}\sqrt{\sigma\text{f}}\tag4$$

Comment: What is "exp" in equation 3?

Comment: @AnalogKid $$\exp\left(x\right):=e^x$$

Comment: Thank you, this is similar to the math I saw online but the explanation makes it very helpful. 

May you provide sources to them? 

Best

Comment: @nndei this is just my knowledge, no source needed :).

Comment: Note that any good EMC text will have the equation Jay Eerland sowed above.  The one text by Henry Ott is considered an EMC bible.

Comment: @JanEerland that's fair :), but I would like to justify my equations to peers. And learn something more about it ;)

Comment: @SteveSh Thank you, I'll give it a look

Comment: @JanEerland, given the formula in (4), the reduction is about 450 dB. Isnt' that too much?
Best